# how to convert month date in a text column into datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

I have a table containing two columns like this:

```
Month_Date  Year
Dec 31      2018
May 01      2020
Jun 05      2021
Jan 18      2022
Jul 19      2019
```

I hope to combine the Month_date and year in the same row and put it in a new column as a datetime format column. Could anyone help, please? I tried to convert the first column to a valid date, but failed because it doesn't show a complete month name.

Comment: which RDBMS you are using ?

Comment: T-SQL in SQL Server management Studio

Comment: YOu can use Concate and substring

Comment: How do you convert ? Have you tried using `convert(datetime, [Month_Date]  + ', ' + [Year], 107)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below approach.

> Approach1:

```
select convert(datetime, [Month_Date]  + ', ' + cast([Year] as varchar(4)), 107) from <TableName>
```

> Approach2:

```
select cast(right(month_date,2)+'-'+left(month_date,3)+'-'+cast([Year] as varchar(4)) as date) from <TableName>
```